# Proper use of context within inner class when using openFileOutput?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, android-context

I am trying to adapt the Android BluetoothChat example to save the InputStream to file using openFileOutput from within the [BluetoothChatService](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html) class. When using the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory and saving to the sdcard using filewriter there is no problem, but using the openFileOutput method with MODE_PRIVATE returns a nullPointerException as mentioned in several other questions/answers. I cant for the life of me figure out the correct way to get the correct context.

```
   private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private Context mContext;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Save to file
                    String FILENAME = "chat.txt";

                    FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(bytes);
                    fos.close();
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right now mContext is null. You're not assigning anything to it anywhere. You could change your constructor signature to pass it in:

```
public ConnectedThread(Context context, BluetoothSocket socket) {
    this.mContext = context;
    ...
}
```

If you're actually following the example, you could do the same type of thing in the `BluetoothChatService`... note that they don't do anything with the context passed in. Store that context off in a field and it would also be accessible to the `ConnectedThread`.

Comment: Keeping a reference to a Context this way will probably leak.

Comment: This thing needs a destructor at the least. I think a better approach is to get a reference to the application context, as there is no display related code here.